# Renaming an uploaded file using Multer doesn't work (Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload, multer

I'm trying to upload a file from a HTML form using Express.js and Multer. I've managed to save the file to the desired location (a folder named *uploads*).

However, I'd like to rename the file while uploading it because, by default, Multer gives it a strange name such as:

> 5257ee6b035926ca99923297c224a1bb

Might be a hexadecimal time stamp or so but I need a more explicit name in order to call a script on it later.

I've followed the explanation found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214237/rename-a-file-with-multer-is-not-working) but it doesn't do anything more than it used to: uploading the file with the hexa name.

Also, the two events **onFileUploadStart** and **onFileUploadComplete** never seem to be triggered as I don't get anything logged in my console.

I am using two separate files for the server and the routing:

***app.js***

```
/**
 * Dependencies
 */

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/**
 * Importation of routes
 */
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var recog = require('./routes/recog');

/**
 * Express
 */
var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// pour contrer les erreurs de cross domain
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

/**
 * Routes
 */
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/recog', recog);

module.exports = app;
```

***recog.js***

```
/**
 * Requirements
 */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        console.log("Rename...");
        return filename + Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function () {
        console.log("Upload is starting...");
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function () {
        console.log("File uploaded");
    }
});

/**
 * Upload d'une image
 */
router.post('/upload', uploads.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Front-end is calling");
    res.json({status: 'success', data: 'Fichier chargé.\nOrgane sélectionné : ' + req.body.organ});
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have been digging around but I can't figure out what the problem is as I am quite new to Node.js and JavaScript in general.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 28):

The usage for Multer has changed.

Currently Multer constructor accepts only three options:

1. dist/storage
2. fileFilter
3. limits

now rename, onFileUploadStart, onFileUploadComplete would not work.

however renaming can be done using DiskStorage

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

have a look at these links:

- https://github.com/expressjs/multer
- [multer callbacks not working ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045027/multer-callbacks-not-working)

Answer (score 13):

I know this post is dated. I want to contribute to those who may arrive later. Below is a full functional server script to handle multiple uploaded pictures with random saved pictures names and file extension.

```
var express = require("express");
var multer = require("multer");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var uuid = require("uuid");

// Allow cross origin resource sharing (CORS) within our application
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploadedimages/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

// "files" should be the same name as what's coming from the field name on the client side.
app.post("/upload", upload.array("files", 12), function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.files);
    console.log("files = ", req.files);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: `destination` can also simply be a `string` when a dynamic upload directory isn't needed. e.i. `destination: "uploadedImages/"` instead of `destination: function (...`

Answer (score 5):

try this way which i'm using

```
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log(file);
      var fileObj = {
        "image/png": ".png",
        "image/jpeg": ".jpeg",
        "image/jpg": ".jpg"
      };
      if (fileObj[file.mimetype] == undefined) {
        cb(new Error("file format not valid"));
      } else {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + fileObj[file.mimetype])
      }
    }
  })

  var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Answer (score 4):

we give a random name to file with the help of date and appends the original file extension with help of `file.mimetype`

try console.log(file.mimetype) you will get the file name and extension separated by '/' then I split it to array and fetch the extension from it.
Try the below code.

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ '.' +extension)
  }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Answer (score 3):

File has structure like this:

```
{
"fieldname": "avatar",
"originalname": "somefile.pdf",
"encoding": "7bit",
"mimetype": "application/pdf",
"destination": "./uploads",
"filename": "36db44e11b83f4513188f649ff445a2f",
"path": "uploads\\36db44e11b83f4513188f649ff445a2f",
"size": 1277191
```

}

The next example saves file with it's original name an extension and not with the strange name like it is by default. 
(Instead of "file.originalname" you can save it as you want)

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads') //Destination folder
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname) //File name after saving
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I implemented the following solutions, which generates a random name for files and appends the original file extension (I assume that my extension is after the last . )

```
var path = require('path');

    var options = multer.diskStorage({ destination : 'uploads/' ,
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, (Math.random().toString(36)+'00000000000000000').slice(2, 10) + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
      }
    });

    var upload= multer({ storage: options });

    router.post('/cards', upload.fields([{ name: 'file1', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'file2', maxCount: 1 }]), function(req, res, next) {
    /*
      handle files here
      req.files['file1']; //First File
      req.files['file2']; //Second File
      req.body.fieldNames;//Other Fields in the form

    */
    });
```

In the `MULTER` documentation you'll find this:

> The disk storage engine gives you full control on storing files to
>   disk.

> There are two options available, **destination** and **filename**. They are
>   both functions that determine where the file should be stored.

> **Note:** You are responsible for creating the directory when providing
>   destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make
>   sure that the directory is created for you.
>
> filename is used to determine what the file should be named inside the
>   folder. If no filename is given, each file will be given a random name
>   that doesn't include any file extension.
>
> **Note:** Multer will not append any file extension for you, your function
>   should return a filename complete with an file extension.